# How to kill a child process

Tags: python, fork

I've found several methods to kill a child process. I would like to use the os.kill(pid). But it doesn't work, I guess it should though.

```
def onExit():
    os.kill(logProc, 0)
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit
    return

button.clicked.connect(onExit)

logProc=os.fork()
if logProc>0:
    proc()
```

Comment: `os.kill` doesn't kill a process, it just sends specified signal to the process (yes, this is confusing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass signals like `signal.SIGKILL` (9), `signal.SIGTERM` (15) to kill the process.

```
import signal

...

os.kill(logProc, signal.SIGKILL)
```

According to Linux `kill(2)`:

> If  `sig`  is `0`, then **no signal is sent**, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID  orprocess group ID.