# Functions that stop after x time Python

Tags: python, function, time

I am working at a Python project, and I reached a point where I need a function to stop and return after a x time, that is passed as a parameter. A simple example:

```
def timedfunc(time_to_stop):
    result = None
    while (time_has_not_passed):
        do()
    return result
```

I explain:
When time has passed, `timedfunc` stops and interrupts everything in it, and jumps right to `return result`. So, what I need is a way to make this function work as long as possible (`time_to_stop`), and then to return the `result` variable, which is as accurate as possible (More time, more calculations, more accuracy). Of course, when time is out, also `do()` stops. To better understand, I say that the function is continuosly changing the value of `result`, and once the time has passed it returns the current value. (`do()` stands for all the calculations that change `result`)

I just made a simple example to better explain what I want:

```
def multiply(time):
    result = 10
    while time_has_not_passed:
        temporary = result*10  #Actually much more time-consuming, also like 3 minutes.
        temporary /= 11
        result = temporary
    return result
```

This explains what kind of calculations `do()` makes, and I need as many *10/11 as python can do in, for example, 0.5 sec.
I know that this pretty complicated, but any help would be great.

Comment: how is that function doing something in a timed way? is it already asynchronous? if so, you might know how this is working

Comment: What the function do() actually does is relevant to the problem here, could you elaborate?

Comment: Similar to Olivier's point: `do()`'s implementation changes how you solve this. This guide on asynchronous behavior with `subprocess` might be helpful (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html), or this thread on using `signal` to kill child processes: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259873/how-to-kill-a-child-process)

Comment: Thanks, an asynchronous function is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

program()
if (time.time()-start_time)>0.5: #you can change 0.5 to any other value you want
    exit()
```

It is something like this. you can put this if statement right inside your program function too.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use:

```
time.sleep(x)
do()

# OR

now = time()
cooldown = x
if now + cooldown < time():
    do()
```

if you want it to do something for a while

```
now = time()
needed_time = x
while now + needed_time > time():
    do()
```

Comment: How would `sleep` be relevant here??